# Le sens de « phares » dans « des attractions phares »

Tags: sens

Parfois, je rencontre l'expression ''*attractions phares*'', surtout quand le texte parle d'un parc d'attraction.

Ça n'a pas de sens pour moi. Le Larousse dit que phare est un nom: lumières des voitures et projecteur de lumière pour les bateaux... mais n'indique pas que c'est un adjectif. Même chose pour les autres dictionnaires que j'ai consultés.

J'ai deux questions à ce sujet.

1) Peut-on utiliser phare(s) comme adjectif ?

2) Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire exactement quand c'est utilisé comme adjectif ? Est-ce que ça veut dire ''les plus importants'' ?

Comment: https://bescherelle.ca/laccord-du-nom-epithete/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cela veut veut dire « qui attire l'attention de l'usager, du chaland » au même titre qu'un phare attire l'attention des marins.

Answer (score 1):

On trouve souvent "phare" employé comme adjectif pour indiquer "essentiel": http://www.carmf.fr/page.php?page=doc/publications/lettrecarmf/lettre43/points-phares.htm
 L'emploi du pluriel montre aussi qu'il y a une tendance à une conversion du type nom adjectif. L'aspect intéressant à cet égard est la métaphore qui se développe de "phare" comme point de repère géographique important pour aboutir à "phare"comme point essentiel d'une certaine question.